# Using setfacl to give a user full permissions on a folder owned by root

Tags: permissions, sudo

**How do I give a user to do whatever they please inside /var/www/myapp folder, which is owned by `root`, considering that I don't want to change the owner?**

I have setup TeamCity CI. It runs under user account `teamcity`.

Now I created a job that copies build results to /var/www/myapp folder. The folder was initially created by root and is owned by root and I don't want to change that.

So, I wanted to give `teamcity` user permissions to deploy everything into that folder and make the permissions inherited to all existing items, if any:

```
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:teamcity:rwx /var/www/myapp
```

Getfacl reports:

```
getfacl /var/www/myapp
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/www/app1
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:teamcity:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Looks fine, right?

But when I run cp task as a teamcity user, I get an error

```
cp: cannot create regular file '/var/www/myapp/appsettings.json': Permission denied
```

I tested also with

```
sudo runuser -l teamcity -c 'cd /opt/jetbrains/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/f5f9b0bd3b4556c2; cp -Rf appsettings.json /var/www/myapp/'
```

However, if I put `sudo` in front of `cp` then it seems to work fine. But I'd like to avoid adding teamcity to sudoers and spitting `sudo`s all over the place in my TeamCity scripts.

Comment: Does the `teamcity` user have Read access to each of the directory `/var/www`?

Comment: @waltinator No, that's why I was trying to give it all permissions (read,write,execute) using `rwx` flags. The folders were being rewritten every day by an automatic task, so I wanted to apply the rights to the top folder only and make the inner folders inherit it. This approach works fine for other folders that are not owned by `root`.